# Temporarily disabling .hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how to temporarily disable .hover in jquery due to an event on the page.

My current jsfiddle looks like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/4vhajam3/3/
(note that I've lopped off a lot of code for sanity's sake)

The current page setup is that if you mouse over any  with the class "toqc", the image to QC appears in a div below. My need is that if a user clicks on one of the table cells, the mouseover is temporarily disabled (say for 10 seconds) so that they can move around on the page a bit without changing the image in the div.

I looked at a few other questions on this site (namely [jQuery: temporarily disable hover... unintended side effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632755/jquery-temporarily-disable-hover-unintended-side-effect)) and while I understand the code, I can't seem to modify it to work for me. Specifically I was trying

```
    var hoverEnabled = true;

$('.toqc').click(
    function(){
        hoverEnabled = false;
    });

if(hoverEnabled){
    $('#ussfcanl').hover(function() {
    $('#imageholder').html('<img src="http://www.hpc.ncep.noaa.gov/sfc/satsfc.gif" />');                              
});
}
```

But yet, even after clicking on something with the class .toqc, the hover still goes on as soon as I move to another .toqc class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..Kinda lost on where to go from here with my code. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to kill mouseovers for everything on the page, or for some known elements?

Comment: The event is already attached, the code does not magically go back in time and undo that step. Just for fun set the hoverEnabled  to false, the event will not be applied.

Comment: @stakolee Basically for the whole page.

Comment: @epascarello Yeah, I did that to make sure my code wasn't failing the first time around.. still was lost on how to make things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the condition inside, that way it will fire but do nothing.

```
$('#ussfcanl').hover(function() {
    if(hoverEnabled){
        $('#imageholder').html('<img src="http://www.hpc.ncep.noaa.gov/sfc/satsfc.gif" />');                              
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially when loading the page the hover function is created. Therefore the hover still works after you change the hoverEnabled var.

You should check the state of the hoverEnabled within the function like so:

```
//written this way, the function seems to make more sense
$('#ussfcanl').on('mouseenter', function() {
    //checking the type just in case
    if(hoverEnabled === true) {
        $('#imageholder').html('<img src="http://www.hpc.ncep.noaa.gov/sfc/satsfc.gif" />');                              
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there a reason to write the .hover code like you did there [with .on('hover', function]? Is that proper or better?

Comment: `on('hover')` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.9:  http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#quot-hover-quot-pseudo-event

Answer (score 0):

This allows the hover event to become re-enabled after 10 seconds:

```
$('.toqc').click(function(){
  hoverEnabled = false;
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer= setTimeout(function(){
    hoverEnabled=  true;
  },10000);
});
```

Replace your `hover` events with the following, which allows you to change images on click even when `hoverEnabled` is false:

```
$('#ussfcanl').on('mouseover click', function(event) {
  if(event.type!=='mouseover' || hoverEnabled) {
    $('#imageholder').html('<img src="http://www.hpc.ncep.noaa.gov/sfc/satsfc.gif" />');                              
  }
});

$('#mexsfcanl').on('mouseover click',function(event) {
  if(event.type!=='mouseover' || hoverEnabled) {
    $('#imageholder').html('<img src="http://www.hpc.ncep.noaa.gov/sfc/namaksfcwbg.gif" />');
  }
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anLom1zm/5/)**

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get the re-enabling to work on my page, but that's no biggie. I really appreciate you going the extra step in helping me out!

Comment: That could happen if you don't declare the `timer` variable.  I should have pointed that out in my post, but you'll see it in my fiddle.

Comment: Whoops.. there it is.. My apologies for not seeing that in your fiddle. Got busy at work with other things and must have glanced over it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to `.hover()` that you seem to be missing.

The first is that events are bound on page load. That's why, as other answers have mentioned, you need to put the condition inside the event fired callback (the `function() {}` part), like so:

```
$('#ussfcanl').hover(function() {
    if(hoverEnabled){
        // do stuff on hover
    }
});
```

The second part is that the jQuery `.hover()` method is really a shorthand for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. Calling .hover() with one function will cause that function to fire for both events, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

So you probably want to use two callback functions with this method, the first to tell the browser what to do when the mouseenter event is fired, and the second for the mouseleave event. See [the jQuery docs on .hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$('#ussfcanl').hover(
    function() {
        if(hoverEnabled){
            // do stuff on mouseenter
        }
    },
    function() {
        if(hoverEnabled){
            // do stuff on mouseleave
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation.